# Architecture for high thoroughput streaming data application in C#?

Tags: streaming

My current project:  We are connecting to remote servers which are flooding us with health-related data over TCP/IP.  The byte streams received are parsed into objects, and the objects are stored into a SQL Server database.  Clients to the database are expecting to see data in near-real time.

The problem is that our application can't keep up with the maximum output of the remote server.  We have profiled the application, and no methods seem to be overwhelmingly slow.

I'm assuming this problem has been solved at least a few times already.  Does anyone have any suggestions, hints, or references concerning this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking down larger portions of the operation, and looking for alternative, quicker methods. For example, the data parsing individual functions might not be slow, but overall, it could be taking considerably longer than it should (maybe you should keep the bytes in structs, or use unsafe casting for example). There could be issues with the DB insertion (are you using bulk insert?). Maybe the DB structure needs to be changed. Without more information, it's going to be hard for any of us to pinpoint one single issue.

Comment: thanks for your comments, chrispr.  right now, we are using SqlBulkCopy, which appears to be pretty fast.  also, we're queuing up data items and storing them when the queue count is greater than a pre-defined value.  the database structure itself is pretty straight forward.  we're actually not using any sort of identity fields, and treating the database as a data-dumping ground, of sorts, rather than using it to enforce relationships.

Comment: When you say the application can't keep up with it, where is the bottleneck? If it's CPU, try to find the area that is using the most resources. If it's parsing, there is definitely more efficient ways to parse the data coming in rather than creating a new object for each record.  Also, keep threading in mind. Even raising events for new objects when you're receiving many thousands per second can have a big toll on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said, I'm guessing the bottleneck is probably in your network I/O.

Q: Are you compressing the data?

Comment: the incoming data is not compressed, and we are not compressing it when we store it in the database.  would compression pre-database insertion help?

Comment: If the bottleneck is network I/O (copying data across the wires so that you can insert it into the database), then compressing your network traffic could DEFINITELY help!